# How to improve compilation time for a gigantic boolean expression?

Tags: c++, optimization, compilation

I need to perform a rather complex check over a vector and I have to repeat it thousands and millions of times. To make it more efficient, I translate given formula into C++ source code and compile it in heavily-optimized binary, which I call in my code. The formula is always purely Boolean: only &&, || and ! used. Typical source code looks like this:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>

using DataType = std::vector<bool>;

static const char T = 1;
static const char F = 0;
const std::size_t maxidx = 300;

extern "C" bool check (const DataType& l);

bool check (const DataType& l) {
  assert (l.size() == maxidx);
  return (l[0] && l[1] && l[2]) || (l[3] && l[4] && l[5]); //etc, very large line with && and || everywhere
}
```

I compile it as follows:

```
g++  -std=c++11 -Ofast -march=native -fpic -c check.cpp
```

Performance of the resulting binary is crucial.

It worked perfectly util recent test case with the large number of variables (300, as you can see above). With this test case, g++ consumes more than 100 GB of memory and freezes forever.

My question is pretty straightforward: how can I simplify that code for the compiler? Should I use some additional variables, get rid of vector or something else?

EDIT1: Ok, here is the screenshot from top utility.

[image]

cc1plus is busy with my code. The *check* function depends on 584 variables (sorry for a imprecise number in the example above) and it contains 450'000 expressions.

I would agree with @akakatak's comment below. It seems that g++ performs something O(N^2).

Comment: Uuh... what? 100GB? Not with this code. Sounds like you have a bug elsewhere.

Comment: You could try to break it into multiple statements (`bool x1 = l[0] && l[1] && l[2]; bool x2 = l[3] && l[4] && l[5]; bool x3 = x1 || x2;` )

Comment: @Lundin It simplified example, of course. I can't show the real one, but the idea stays the same. Imagine that 'return' line contains several thousands of boolean expressions.

Comment: If the shown example code reproduces the problem when you use the actual expression, then I would recommend reporting a bug to gcc bugtracker with the reproducing example code.

Comment: In the real code, is the size of the `std::vector` known at compile time?

Comment: @user2079303 I do not think that it is a bug. It is a corner case, it is definitely.an interesting example to work with. g++ have to handle too much information at once to perform all the optimizations properly. Still, thanks for the advice!

Comment: @CaptainTrunky sorry if i sound obvious but would it be possible to reduce the number of boolean values in the vector by calculating the needed expressions when the vector gets filled?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, it is known. I can replace it with std::array. However, my algorithm that call this function uses vectors and it does not know their size at compilation time. I will have to cast std::vector to std::array and I assume that such a cast will slow down the whole procedure a lot.

Comment: @CaptainTrunky If you remove the optimisation flags (just compile without any optimisation), the compilation completes or this happens anyhow?

Comment: @CaptainTrunky It doesn't matter, where do you get the 100GB from? Did you mean 100 kilobytes?

Comment: @CaptainTrunky With a size of 300, I don't think you'd see a noticeable slow-down by copying into a temporary `std::bitset` or `std::array`, and it would be interesting to see if gcc has the same behaviour using those containers.

Comment: @Zaiborg It is reasonable question. I can try to do this using logic minimization tools like espresso. However, this will require more or less significant code modifications and I'd prefer to avoid this.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks, I'll try to implement it in couple of days and post the results here.

Comment: @Lundin I undestand your skepticism :). I'll add here output from 'top' tool in couple of hours.

Comment: I tried to compile repeating of `(l[0] && l[1] && l[2]) || ...` in a return-statement where `l` is `std::vector<bool> const &` with `g++ -c test.cpp -O3`. The compilation time seems `O(N^2)` where `N` is the number of repeating. For `N = 2048`, 1.5 GB is used, and for `N = 4096`, at least 8 GB is used for my environment.

Comment: Stupid question: what happens if you lift out all the bools first and then test those values? E.g., `bool l0= l[0]`, etc.

Comment: I suppose your DNF representation was derived from an original problem? Since the compiler seems to try to find a more efficient representation anyway, shouldn't you use your original (hopefully smaller) representation in this way instead?

Comment: @AlbertHendriks Yes, I'm checking a DNF formula. However, I'm not able to use original CNF formula - I have to inspect each DNF term in all details. In other words, I have to get rid of each 'don't care' value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a necro-posting a little bit, but I still should share my results.

The solution proposed by Thilo in comments above is the best. It's very simple and it provides measurable compile time improvement. Just split your expression into chunks of the same size. But, in my experience, you have to choose an appropriate sub expression length carefully - you can encounter significant execution performance drop in case of large number of sub expressions; a compiler will not be able to optimize the whole expression perfectly.

Comment: Is this 3SAT? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem

Comment: @KennyOstrom The problem in my question is not 3SAT. But the whole project relied a lot on SAT solving and SAT-counting, so I had to perform various manipulations over Boolean expressions. I tried to implement some JIT-like techniques to improve overall performance and faced introduced problem: some Boolean expressions are too heavy for GCC.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious optimization here is to toss out the vector and use a bit-field, based on the fastest possible integer type:

```
uint_fast8_t item [n];
```

You could write this as

```
#define ITEM_BYTES(items) ((items) / sizeof(uint_fast8_t))
#define ITEM_SIZE(items) ( ITEM_BYTES(items) / CHAR_BIT + (ITEM_BYTES(items)%CHAR_BIT!=0) )
...
uint_fast8_t item [ITEM_SIZE(n)];
```

Now you have a chunk of memory with *n* segments, where each segment is the ideal size for your CPU. In each such segment, set bits to 1=true or 0=false, using bitwise operators.

Depending on how you want to optimize, you would group the bits in different ways. I would suggest storing 3 bits of data in every segment, since you always wish to check 3 adjacent boolean numbers. This mean that "n" in the above example will be the total number of booleans divided by 3.

You can then simply iterate through the array like:

```
bool items_ok ()
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    if( (item[i] & 0x7u) == 0x7u )
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

---

With the above method you optimize:

- The data size in which comparisons are made, and with it possible alignment issues.
- The overall memory use.
- The number of branches needed for the comparisons.

This also rules out any risks of ineffectiveness caused by the usual C++ meta programming. I would never trust `std::vector`, `std::array` or `std::bitfield` to produce optimal code.

Once you have the above working you can always test if `std::bitfield` etc containers yields the very same, effective machine code. If you find that they spawned any form of unrelated madness in your machine code, then don't use them.

Comment: Good answer, but it would be interesting to compare with same approach, but with std::array. It should not cause much (or any?) overhead.

Comment: @ErikAlapää Having programmed to and fro in C++ for the past 20 years, I have zero trust in any container with a `std::` prefix. _Maybe_ if you have the latest and greatest version of gcc and nothing else, you'll get an equally efficient result as what I proposed here. I would never rely on that though.

Comment: I have programmed in C++ to and fro for the last 24 years, and STL is one of the most efficient libraries in the world. When I am in plain C I miss it sorely, almost as much as I miss destructors and smart pointers. Of course, a std::vector uses malloc/new, but a std::array is pretty bare-bones.

Comment: @ErikAlapää As always, disassemble the results. Anything else is just subjective speculation over how wonderful/horrible STL is. There's the C++ fan boys who never want to hear that C++ is slower than C, and there's the old, bitter C programmers who never wants to hear that C++ is as fast as C. Unfortunately, neither will see reason even when you rub the disassembly in their face.

Comment: Disassembly is good, facts and measurements are paramount. But some things are better in C++/STL by design, e.g. std::sort being faster than C qsort since comparison operator can be bound at compile time.

Comment: In this specific case, it I don't think `std::array` in itself will be slower. But when you start implementing the above function as a functor, then apply something from `<algorithm>` on top of it... well. It may or may not be as efficient. Anyway, the point here is that's there just no chance that a `std::vector<bool>` will be anywhere near as fast as the above method.